# Custom Activity in Journey Builder gets a 400 error when it tries to POST to an external API endpoint... What happens next? Do they keep going?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, custom-activity

When a Custom Activity in Journey Builder tries to POST to the app's external API endpoint and gets a 400 error, what happens to the subscriber's flow through the journey?

- Does SFMC retry the API call a certain number of times? Indefinitely?
- Does the subscriber get ejected from the Journey?
- Do they get permanently stuck in the custom Journey Builder Activity?
- Or is the error simply logged and they move onto the next step? And if so, where is it logged?

**To be clear, this is asking about the call SFMC makes to the host of the app (SFMC->Heroku) NOT the call the app makes to SFMC (Heroku->SFMC).**

Answer (score 2):

- Does SFMC retry the API call a certain number of times? Indefinitely? *Answer:* No, there's no retry. There's only a retry if your execute request times out, read further on: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/custom-activity-config.htm
- Does the subscriber get ejected from the Journey? *Answer:* I haven't tested this recently but I think so, this will be an easy test to perform.
- Do they get permanently stuck in the custom Journey Builder Activity? *Answer:* Similar to above no, they just get rejected.
- Or is the error simply logged and they move onto the next step? And if so, where is it logged? *Answer:* It doesn't move to the next step, the only way it will move to the next step is if your activity has branches and you return an HTTP 200 with the corresponding branch key.

Comment: "and you return an HTTP 200 with the corresponding branch key"